# When creating multipage application, what is best method to show elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web application using asp.net and MVC.The content of the web application is large. Is it wise to write all the code in one view and use show/hide to display needed divs on click OR to write as individual views and use load to display div as and when required. Also I need the best solution which will make a faster, response web app and does not need high bandwidth to load.
I am currently using jquery only and not other javascript libraries

Answer (score 0):

Since you using ASP.NET MVC, then You can create
**one view**

> where you can add the content that you need always regardless of any
>   click

and
**one/more Partialviews**

> the content which you need to hide/show on click.

It will help you to keep huge content in clean way, and also on click you can load only required partial views.

Comment: But will this method will be faster and responsive.... Read somewhere that single page structure will be faster

Comment: Single page structure will be faster, but you have to show/hide some content on click,so for you scenario above is the best and also there is no much performance difference in MVC since it basically contains HTML code itself and it will not render